# How to read data from PostGIS in DotNet (VB.Net/C#)

Tags: postgis, arcgis-engine, .net

I have stored my data in PostGIS (PostgrSQL). Now I want to read
the data in DotNet ArcEngine Application using VB.NET/C#.

Anyone know how to read the data from PostGIS in .Net?

Regards

Comment: I want to read a esri shapfile as a layer that is stored in PostGIS so that I can load it into ArcEngine

Comment: PostGIS doesn't store Esri Shapefiles. It stores `geometry`/`geography` data types, and fetches data thorough a database connection—not through file IO, as is the case for Shape *files*. I'm going to guess your question asks "How to read geometry data from PostGIS in .Net"

Comment: Not really an answer, but take a look at this [old] code for [zigGIS](http://code.google.com/p/ziggis/)

Comment: OK How to read geometry/geography let say Country so that I can load it as layer in ArcEngine.

Answer (score 1):

I myself load geometry from an Oracle database into .NET. I use de OGC libraries supplied by [GDAL](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).
It is not pleasant to handle the geometry this way. In retrospect I would try and use the libraries from the [SharpMap application](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110213533/http://sharpmap.codeplex.com:80/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ArcGIS 10, the easiest way to view PostGIS Data in an ArcEngine Application, is to create a [query layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_a_query_layer/00s50000000n000000/) in ArcMap, and then save it as a .lyr file. 
You should then be able to view the data in your ArcEngine Application

If you want to Edit data or do complicated queries, you can use the new [ISQLWorkspace interface](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/0001/000100000480000000.htm).